# The import org.apache.flink.table cannot be resolved

Tags: apache-flink

I've installed Apache Flink 1.4 and I've implemented several tasks using the Dataset API. Now, I want to try using the Table API but it doesn't seem like I can import it.

**Is there something else I need to install?** It doesn't seem like anyone else is having any issues importing the table API.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import the `flink-table` dependency in your pom.xml, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can find a suitable version in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table).

Comment: This is documented here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/. It's also worth noting that the table API has been much improved since version 1.4.